# $_SESSION does not store

Tags: php, mysql, session

My user validation in my login is working fine, the only problem is that it doesn't stores the PHP SESSION. I've debugged it to see if any session were stored, but they werent. Because when i send the user to the destination page.

The destination page checks with `if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { etc.. }`
if the user is logged in or not. Otherwise it sends the user back to the login page. So that is what is going wrong, it sends the user back to the login page.. and ofcourse to confirm the debug says NULL on all.

**PHP5:**

```
<?php require ('../lib/config.php'); ?>
<?php
ob_start();

if (isset($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
$tbl_name='users';
$user_name='Username';
$pass_name='Password';
$salt='';

mysql_connect("$cchost", "$ccuser", "$ccpass")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$ccname")or die("cannot select DB");


$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];
$username=str_replace(' ','_', $myusername);
$password=hash('whirlpool', $salt . $mypassword);

$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE $user_name='$username' and $pass_name='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$donator=$row['donator'];
$player=$row['player'];
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($donator == '1') {
$_SESSION['donator'] = $donator;
}
if ($player == '1') {
$_SESSION['player'] = $player;
}
if($count==1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header("Location: index_ucp.php");
}
else {
header("Location: login_ucp.php?err=1");
}
}
else {
header("Location: login_ucp.php?err=9");
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php notice how `session_start()` is always called before dealing with `$_SESSION` in all of the examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use session_start(); after ob_start();

Comment: Any reason why `session_start` must be invoked _after_ `ob_start`?

Comment: Dohh, ofcourse. My little mistakes.. again.

Comment: @zamnuts no, it doesn't have to. you don't have to call ob_start at all. that's old php.

Comment: @zamnuts If we start the session we could 'write' to the session and ofcourse create our fields.

Comment: @r3wt I've still had my problems so i had to include ob_flush and ob_start ofcourse.

Comment: @SumanBiswas IMO, that is terrible advice.

Answer (score 2):

be sure and call `session_start()` at the beginning of all your pages where you want to use sessions, or set `session.auto_start = 1;` in php.ini

**EDIT while i'm here let me scold you about the way you are hashing passwords**

A wise man once told me to never roll my own password hash. i now will pass the secret on to you. Since php 5.3, php has built in functions for hashing and verifying passwords. these functions are :

`password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

password hash takes one argument, the plaintext string to hash. password verify takes two arguments, the plaintext string and the hash to test for a match. easy peasy.

```
//first we define how costly we want this to be for our cpus to calculate this hash.
$options = [
        'cost' => 11,
    ];

$encrypted = password_hash($plainText, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);//BCRYPT hashes look like so $ STRENGTH $. HASH / SALT

//this is useful because you never have to remember the salt or strength for a given password hash

if(password_verify($plainText,$encdata))
{
    //good to go
}else{
    //wrong password!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If

```
session_start();
```

is used in conf.php .Then there should be no problem .

But if there is no such statement then insert this at the start.

Or include File havind session_start(); code.